# How to rename files in Powershell with three digits and odd numbers?

Tags: windows, powershell, rename

Pretty novice to using powershell.

Trying to rename several .wav files that need to be in an odd sequential order.

I've found from another post from here how to rename multiple files in odd increments but can't figure out how to format them as **"001_title.wav", 003_title.wav, 005_title.wav etc.**

Stumped with trying to implement '{0:d3}'.

Should I be using that?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks.

```
$path = "\path\to\files"
$oddNumbersArray = 0..500 | % {$_ *2 +1}
$i = 0
Get-ChildItem $path -Filter *.wav | % {Rename-Item $_ -NewName ("$($oddNumbersArray[$i])_title.wav") '{0:d3}' -f $($oddNumbersArray[$i]) ;$i++}
```

Comment: Please don't use the `script` tag. It means *nothing at all*. Every SO question is about scripts one way or another. The tag is so bad it will was deleted in the past and is going to be deleted again very soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `-NewName` expression should look like this:

```
... |Rename-Item -NewName { '{0:d3}_title.wav' -f $oddNumbersArray[$script:i++] }
```

The `{}` brackets ensure the pipeline binder re-calculates the value for each input item, and the `script:` scope modifier is required because we're *writing* to a variable in a parent scope.

---

FWIW you don't have to "pre-calculate" your odd numbers - you can increment your counter variable by 2 instead:

```
$path = "\path\to\files"
$oddCounter = 1
Get-ChildItem $path -Filter *.wav |Rename-Item -NewName { '{0:d3}_title.wav' -f $oddNumbersArray[($script:i += 2)] }
```